# News feed using Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, feed

I am developing a news feed backend for multiple applications. The idea is that a user can subscribe to multiple groups and receive posts from the groups that he is subscribed to via push.

I was thinking of: on creating a new post have a `create_post_task(content)` that goes to the Celery `feed` queue, so that Celery workers can consume it. What I am not sure is what should I do afterwards to deliver the posts to the clients, dynamically create a new RabbitMQ queue for each group, and route the posts to the respective queue, so that subscribed clients will be pushed the posts from those queues? If so, how do I do that after the task was consumed? Is having a lot of RabbitMQ/Celery queues a problem? Any suggestions on an effective solution would be valuable.

Comment: Look at the [django-feedly](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Feedly) This is a brilliant package to create newsfeed for your application.

Comment: @AamirAdnan, it looks very interesting about abstracting fanouts, but I did not find any information on post delivery. How does the post reach the client application via push, so the user doesn't have to refresh his feed?

Comment: As soon as user performs an action you are going to generate a feedly activity which will be inserted into user feed and later a fanout operation will be done using celery. That activity which you just inserted you also need to publish it e.g. by using redis pubsub so that all followers receive real time update on front end e.g. by using Server Sent Events (SSE). That is the stack I have used while working on it.